# How to install Ubuntu server 12.04 on a new HP Microserver Proliant Gen8 G2020?

Tags: 12.04, server, system-installation, hp

I am new to all of this.

I have just bought a new HP Proliant Gen8 G2020T microserver. I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 i386 version on the server. I have downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 on a USB from this link: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/thank-you?distro=server&bits=32&release=lts

Is this the right version?

I have powered the server and I get an option of F9 or F10. Which one do I choose?

Could you please give me step by step instructions?

Your help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a dual-core 2.5GHz Pentium, so you should use Ubuntu **12.04.3 LTS** Server **64-bit**.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/thank-you?distro=server&bits=64&release=lts

---

***F9 or F10:***

Read what's on screen.

You need to manually select boot source, and select USB device.

*I haven't yet tried this on the HP MicroServer G8, but the G6 and G7 were straight forward.*